# QGLBuffer usage

Tags: qt, qglwidget

I have some problems in understanding how to use QGLBuffer to render simple objects(like Rectangle for example). I'm trying to make selection rectangle for my app. here's the code example of what im doing :

```
class PlotGLWidget : public QGLWidget
 {
     Q_OBJECT
private:
QGLBuffer* m_ZoomRectBuffer;
public:
void initializeGL();
void paintGL();
void drawZoomRect();
};
void PlotGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
setMouseTracking (true);
glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
m_ZoomRectBuffer=new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
m_ZoomRectBuffer->create();
m_ZoomRectBuffer->bind();
m_ZoomRectBuffer->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::DynamicDraw);
m_ZoomRectBuffer->allocate(8*sizeof(double));
m_ZoomRectBuffer->release();
}
void PlotGLWidget::paintGL()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, this->width(), this->height());
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,100, 0,100, -1.0l, 0.0l);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
drawZoomRect();
}
void PlotGLWidget::drawZoomRect()
{
GLdouble vertices[] = {10, 10, 0, 
                      10,  20, 0, 
                      20,  20, 0, 
                      20, 10, 0}; 

     GLubyte indices[] = {0,1,2,3};
if(m_ZoomRectBuffer->bind()){
m_ZoomRectBuffer->write(0,vertices,sizeof(double)*12);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, 0);
glDrawElements( GL_POLYGON, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,indices);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
m_ZoomRectBuffer->release();     
}
```

in spite of being just example im sure there are some mistakes in my code and my understanding of the technology. Code compiles without mistakes and runs, but nothing is drawing.

Comment: I think i solved it simple inattention,must allocate 12*sizeof(double) not 8.

Comment: I know this question is old, but maybe it's useful for some future problems: You could just have written `sizeof(vertices)`. This will take any changes into account, both the number of elements and the type used (float or double). PS: In 99% cases, float is enough in rendering 3D scenes and saves 50% graphic memory.